# Top TableView Cell not being updated

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am currently developing an application using MvvmCross and Xamarin iOS.
The main view of the application is split into two. The lower half of the view is a table view.

The table view is populated by an async proses that works correctly.

If a user taps to select the item, they are navigated to another view that enables them to update the selected item. The update causes the data source to be reloaded (as the edit may have affected other items) and the table view to reload.

The table view is not in view during the reload process; however the reload is performed on the main thread.

In all cases this works correctly, apart from when the top visible row is selected. In this instance the cell is never updated. Each time it is selected for reuse the view renders with the initial data that it was created with.

From the console output I can see that prepare for reuse is being invoked on all of the cells. I can also confirm that the reload operation on the table is being invoked on the main thread.

The table data source (extended from MvxSimpleTableSource) does invoke the overload for GetOrCreateCellFor and the data for the bound items is updated.
All of my investigations have not been able to resolve the issue.

Please can anyone help.

Update: I have now resolved the issue bit would like to understand why it is happening.

The issue seems to have been due to the oveload for the RowSelected method of the MvxSimpleTableSource.

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    try
    {
        if (!this.parent.ViewModel.IsLocked)
        {
            /*    Removing the following code enables the top visable cell to
            *     be reloaded correctly
            if (this.highlightedRow == null || this.highlightedRow.Row != indexPath.Row)
            {
                var cell = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath) as CustomTableCellWithImage;
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    cell.ContentView.BackgroundColor = this.parent.HighlightColor;
                 }
            }
            *     End of removed code
            */
            this.parent.ViewModel.SetNavigationDate();
            base.RowSelected(tableView, indexPath);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.parent.ViewModel.LogError(ex, "RowSelected indexPath: {0}", indexPath.ToString());
    }
}
```

The bound command is async, and the code works for all selected rows unless it is the top visible row.

When a user selects the top visible row the cell seems to get into a state where the view is never update, even when SetNeedsDisplay is directly invoked.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I do not know useful the code would be without the entire solution. effectively the process for the refresh is as follows  `InvokeOnMainThread(async() => { await this.ViewModel.ReloadDataToDate(); await this.TableView.ReloadData();}`

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible sample if you expect someone to help you.

Comment: Is it possible that the line `var cell = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath) as CustomTableCellWithImage` is causing a refernce to the cell to be retained? I initially discounted this as the process works for any other cell apart from the top visible cell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], rather than a snippet of your code.

Comment: It is not possible for me to provide a minmial and complete example. I have outlined the issue. Identified where the problem is being caused and how it has been resolved. As I outlined in the question the code works for all instances other than the top visible cell. I would be greatful anyone can enlighten me as to why ONLY the top visible cell would become corrupted and not ever update. I suspect that it is due to the animations that are taking place when the new view is animated onto the screen. However this does not explain why any other cell works if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain, but I do believe calling this might be the issue:

```
var cell = this.GetCell(tableView, indexPath) as CustomTableCellWithImage;
```

`GetCell` is a method called by the OS when getting cells to display. I don't think you should call this yourself. Instead you can use `tableView.CellAt(indexPath)` so try replacing the above line with:

```
var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath) as CustomTableCellWithImage;
```